# Where was Tivarov (Russia or Poland area)?

Tags: poland, russia

My grandmother came from a place called Tivarov around 1910.  It was a town or small city, partly or mostly Jewish.  We're not sure exactly where that place was and I'd love to know the location and the nation at that time.  I only know it was in an area of shifting boundaries so it could have been Russia or Poland.

Does this place name ring a bell to anyone?

Comment: Did your grandmother tell you she came from a place called Tivarov around 1910, or did you read that in a document?  If the latter what was the document?

Comment: There's no document.  This info is from my mother.  Interestingly, my sister-in-law had a grandparent from the same place.  So we're sure the place was real but don't know where it was, and others might spell it differently.

Comment: this looks quite promising; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyvriv

Comment: Wow, thanks Andra!!!!